# Bash - comparing output of two commands

Tags: linux, bash, curl, terminal, string-comparison

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

CMDA=$(curl -sI website.com/example.txt | grep Content-Length)

CMDB=$(curl -sI website.com/example.txt | grep Content-Length)

if [ "CMDA" == "CMDB" ];then
  echo "equal";
else
  echo "not equal";
fi
```

with this output

```
root@abcd:/var/www/html# bash ayy.sh
not equal
```

which should be "equal" instead of "not equal". What did I do wrong?

Thnaks

Comment: You forgot the `$` for the variables there. This is what you need: `if [ "$CMDA" == "$CMDB" ];then`

Comment: @janos thanks, works, if you want to you can write thit as an answer so I can mark it as the right one

Comment: Alright, there you go. Threw in a few extra tips too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot the `$` for the variables `CMDA` and `CMDB` there. This is what you need:

```
if [ "$CMDA" = "$CMDB" ]; then
```

I also changed the `==` operator to `=`,
because `man test` only mentions `=`,
and not `==`.

Also, you have some redundant semicolons. The whole thing a bit cleaner:

```
if [ "$CMDA" = "$CMDB" ]; then
  echo "equal"
else
  echo "not equal"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string "CMDA" with "CMDB", you should instead compare the variables using $ like ${CMDA}